# how to calculate surface area bounded by $g(\theta) = (\cos(\theta) , \sin^3(\theta))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

let $g(\theta) = (\cos(\theta) , \sin^3(\theta))$ find the surface area bounded by this curve.
$ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $

this was an exam question from today i had VERY hard time calculating the integral and i failed to calculate . i want to be sure about the way i solved this question :

Let $ S(r,\theta) = (r\cos(\theta) , r\sin^3(\theta))$ the surface we want to find  its area.

$ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $

$ 0 \leq r \leq 1 $

$ ||S_r\times S_{\theta}|| = 2r\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) + r\sin^2(\theta) $

so S = $ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2r\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) + r\sin^2(\theta) ~dr~d\theta$

and i failed to calculate this , the  final answer is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ according to the integral calculator.

is my solution alright ?

Comment: anyone i really need to know it is the only question that i was afraid of . and sadly they are gonna take 5-6 points for sure because i didn't calculate it

Comment: yes i got that and i said that $ sin^2(\theta) = $1 - cos^2(\theta )$ so plugging that in $sin^2(\theta) ^ 2 $

Comment: Anyway, this is a plane curve, so I wouldn't bother with the parametrization of the surface. I would just sketch the curve to make sure there are no surprise self-intersections, and then use one of the ways of getting the area surrounded by a close curve. Those are usually taught together with Green's theorem in the plane. Have you covered those? That way it becomes a routine trig integral.

Comment: i though about green therom but i couldn't find " Nicee " Vector field that would get the surface area through green therom

Comment: type error i wrote r in the exam too i will change that here

Comment: right its $ \frac{3\pi}{4} $ because integrating on r we get half it was my bad but i see that this way alright

Comment: Yes, your method is all right, and gives the correct answer in the end.

Comment: thank you so much sir .

Comment: But, I would still sketch a picture. If the boundary curve were slightly different you might not be able parametrize the region as $r(x(\theta),y(\theta))$. Mind you, if this were not the case the resulting errors often cancel in the integral, but even so :-)